# Gridview, system.data.datarowview' does not contain a property

Tags: c#, asp.net

iam getting a error when trying to make a dropdown list in asp.net. hoping you guys can help because i dont know what else to try anymore.. 
 The error: "system.data.datarowview' does not contain a property with the name  'Suppstatus'.", sounds like ive spelled something wrong but ive tripple checked.

template code:

```
                     <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("Suppstatus") %>' Visible="false" ID="lblsuppStatus" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlSupStatus"> </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
```

Code behind:

```
        protected void grvSupplierStatus_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && GridView1.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
                {
                    DropDownList ddlSupStatus = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlSupstatus");
                    Label lblsuppstatus = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblsuppStatus");
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    ds = GetYesNoValue("Suppstatus");
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt = ds.Tables[0];
                    ddlSupStatus.DataSource = dt;
                    ddlSupStatus.DataTextField = "Suppstatus";
                    ddlSupStatus.DataValueField = "Suppstatus";
                    ddlSupStatus.DataBind();
                    ddlSupStatus.Items.FindByValue(lblsuppstatus.Text).Selected = true;

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

        }  

        public DataSet GetYesNoValue(string ColumnName)
        {
            DataTable dtVal = new DataTable();
            DataColumn column;
            DataRow row;

            column = new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            column.ColumnName = ColumnName;
            dtVal.Columns.Add(column);

            DataSet dsVal = new DataSet();

            dtVal.Rows.Add("--Select--");
            dtVal.Rows.Add("Yes");
            dtVal.Rows.Add("No");

            dsVal.Tables.Add(dtVal);

            return dsVal;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a circuitous  approach to insert your data. You could also

replace

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlSupStatus" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

with

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlSupStatus" Selected='<%# Bind("Suppstatus") %>'> 
   <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="--Select--"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="No"></asp:ListItem> 
</asp:DropDownList>
```

without any action codebehind

Comment: yeah is what i wanted, couldnt find any info on it, thanks man youre the boss.